# Auto update data extractions in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, automation, extract

I have a Google Sheet that uses the data extraction feature to pull the 'last modified time' and 'last modified by' information. I use this to track updates by staff on a couple of key documents. I have this data conditional formatted by date to quikcly highlight changes made within the week, over a week, and over a month (green, amber, red).

I would like the data extractions to automatically update, rather than manually using the 'Data extractions' side menu > refresh and manage > refresh all. From my understanding, there isn't a way to do this with the current features, and as the extracts don't appear to be regular formula I don't think I'm able to use an auto-update script for formulae as I have done in the past.

Here is a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aSLidQmHw6v49DJU6T35ECG4GYVugcQdEW9Mzg0uibE/edit#gid=0

Many thanks if you are able to help!

Comment: Can you please share a sample sheet with input and desired output, this will help the community to replicate your concern.

Comment: Thank you - I've added an example sheet to my original post.